# How can I create a conditional regex for a named capturing group?

Tags: regex, conditional-statements, named-captures

We are looking to dump our PMDF logs into Splunk and I am trying to parse the PMDF SMTP logs, specifically the message, and I'm hitting an issue where a named capturing group (dst_channel) may or may not have a value. Here is my regex so far:

```
\d{2}\-\w{3}\-\d{4}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.\d{2}\s(?P<src_channel>\w+)\s+(?P<dst_channel>\w+)\s(?P<code>\w+)\s(?P<bytes>\d+)\s(?P<from>\w.+)\srfc822
```

I'm able to match the following message, in which tcp_msx_out_2 is the dst_channel

```
02-Feb-2017 08:00:19.60 tcp_exempt   tcp_msx_out_2 E 2 mailman-bounces@list.xyz.com rfc822;user@xyz.com user@xyz.com <mailman.157.1486040414.29131.xxx@xxx.xyz.com> pmdf list.xyz.com ([x.x.x.x])
```

however, I'm not matching the following logs that doesn't contain a dst_channel value:

```
02-Feb-2017 09:00:01.59 tcp_imap_int              Q 12 xxx@xyz.com rfc822;user@imap-internal.xyz.com user@imap.xyz.com <6940401380880269855036@PT-D69> pmdf  user@imap.xyz.com: smtp;452 4.2.2 Over quota
```

The next named capturing group I have is code E in the first message example, and Q in the second), and when the dst_channel is not there, the regex is not capturing all of the codes.

How can I modify my regex for conditional statements so that if the dst_channel is there, it grabs the value, but if not, regex continues on and is able to consistently grab the values for the other named capturing groups I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use

```
\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{4}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{2}\s+(?P<src_channel>\w+)(?:\s+(?P<dst_channel>\w+))?\s+(?P<code>\w+)\s+(?P<bytes>\d+)\s+(?P<from>\S+)\s+rfc822
                                                                   ^^^                       ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mGBTA4/1).

Basically, replace all `\s` with `\s+` and make the dst channel group optional by wrapping both the `\s+` and the whole dst channel group with an optional non-capturing group.

Also, the `from` group pattern should be replaced with `\S+` (one or more chars other than whitespace) because you want to match an email, and `.+` may - and usually it does - overmatch.

Comment: This is the answer, this regex is way more efficient than mine, less than half the steps

Comment: Wiktor, thx a million for the reply and detailed regex as it's greatly appreciated. Is it safe to say any time I want to signify a non-capturing group I need to wrap both the \s+ and the captured naming group:

(?:\s+(?P<name>\w+))?

Comment: An *optional* capturing group, `(?:...)?`. It does not *always* work (it depends on the patterns around that group), but usually works well, especially after we got rid of all `.*`-like patterns.

Comment: One last question - do I handle the tailing end of the message with a non-capturing group as well?

The end of message one is: smtp;452 4.2.2 Over quota
The end of message two is:  ([1.1.1.1])

I want to be able to capture the source IP if it's listed

Thx

Comment: Thx again for the clarification

Comment: @wiktor - last question, promise! I have a named capturing group for sending_domain as such - (?P<sending_domain>\w.+), but I'm having trouble handling the different values of user@imap.xyz.com: and user@xyz.com (space) 

How do I have regex capture the sending domain no matter what characters are included and how end (: vs space vs whatever follows)?

Thx

Comment: No idea what you mean. Maybe [something like this](https://regex101.com/r/mGBTA4/3).

Comment: Apologize for the lack of clarity - for the sending domain, sometimes I see email addresses conforming to the standard format of user@xyz.com|edu|net (etc)., but sometimes I'll see other formats, such as user@<value>.xyz.com which may or may not contain special characters - user@internal-imap.xyz.com.

I'm trying to end the naming captured group for domain after the email address concludes with |edu|net (etc), and not pick up the special characters (so far I've only seen a colon) before applying the naming captured group for the IP.

Comment: Add a `\b` at the end of the group.

Answer (score 1):

It worked if i changed the `\w+` to a `\w*`

```
\d{2}\-\w{3}\-\d{4}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.\d{2}\s(?P<src_channel>\w+)\s+(?P<dst_channel>\w*)\s(?P<code>\w+)\s(?P<bytes>\d+)\s(?P<from>\w.+)\srfc822
```

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/TUJOxC/1)